# Swing - Custom JButton messes with other components at rollover

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jscrollpane

On a `JPanel` I have a few buttons and `JScrollPane` containing a `JTable`.
One of the buttons is custom made, I have overridden the `paintComponent` method to draw an image.

However, if I set the `contentAreaFilled` or `isOpaque` properties to false (so that the background is not displayed) whenever I roll  over the button the content of the scroll pane is hidden (a grey image appears inside, instead of the table contents). I tried using different layouts for my panel, but got the same result. The only fix I found is setting `rolloverEnabled` to `false` for my custom button, but that is not really an option for me, as I want the button image to change at rollover.

The weird thing is, it only happens when I set one of those two properties mentioned above to false. The button acts perfectly if I do not hide it's background. Just out of curiosity, I tried the same on my other two buttons, which are just `JButtons` with nothing customized, except their size, and it had the same effect on the scroll pane, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the implementation of the custom button. Has anyone encountered this problem or know anything that may help me with this?

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's hard to say, are you using transparent backgrounds or images?

Comment: TL;DR as suggested one [mcve]  is better than 1000 words...

Comment: I know it sounds dumb, but while writing a MCV, I found the issue. So thank you, guys!